# How do you get the HTML phpinfo() on the command line?

Tags: php, html, command-line

I've tried various things like

```
php -r "echo phpinfo();" > test.html
```

and

```
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" | php > test.html
```

but I get a non-HTML dump. (Don't want to expose details here, as it's a company server.)

I guess PHP is detecting what "client" I am on, and serving a text dump instead of the classic purple HTML page?

Comment: That's correct; [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) from the CLI is text only, not rendered as markup. This is stated in the Notes in the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php#refsect1-function.phpinfo-notes)

Comment: Any way to trick it? I'm deploying a web service within my company (but global intranet) and would like to generate an HTML phpinfo() weekly via cron, checked into Perforce, to audit software versions as other developers upgrade pieces.

Comment: Could try to curl your own server from another php script... maybe will return as html then. I've not tested that, so didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: No it can't be tricked.... and remember that the two configurations (web and cli) can be (and normally are) different... using curl (as Randall has suggested) will only return the web config details, not those of the CLI

Comment: @MarkBaker makes a good point that the info can be different!

Comment: If you need to get cli settings for your PHP to render the way it is on web you will have to copy the ini settings to a temporary cli settings, (maybe temporarily), then invoke a script that runs it.

Comment: there might be one trick, if you happen to run php as CGI on your webserver, then you are in luck. just try the same command with `php-cgi` as command instead of `php`.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the information directly from command line:

```
>php -i
```

to search for something you can grep it:

```
>php -i | grep 'memory_limit'
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP is searching for a HTML version of phpinfo on the shell

Comment: @NicoHaase the result is the same. he is asking for command line, and phpInfo() in command line is taken from php -i

Comment: No, the OP asks for the HTML version specifically. When I use `php -i`, it does not dump the HTML version, but a text-version. That is obviously not the same result - even if the configuration output shows the same data in both versions, it does not use the same formatting

Comment: @NicoHaase so what is the answer?

Comment: Why not use the cURL approach recommended by R. Silver?

Answer (score 4):

The user IncredibleHat had the right idea in the comments. I needed a script to return some information from the browser version of phpinfo() and used cURL to get the data I needed.

First make a info.php file:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Then call this file with a cURL GET request using `https://localhost/info.php`. The URI should include the path to wherever you saved you info.php file.

This will return the HTML of phpinfo(). As a bonus, you can change info.php to instead of returning the HTML result and parse it to return the result in a PHP associative array using the code in user Calin S.'s comment in the PHP reference page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php#117961

This way you can easily use anything from the phpinfo() in aother script.

Comment: `phpinfo() outputs plain text instead of HTML when using the CLI mode.` [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), Then it will return plain-text if webserver use cli mode (such like me)

Answer (score 1):

This way helped me to get my phpinfo() in html format:

1. Create some file with phpinfo() in your terminal:

   ```
   echo "<?php phpinfo();" > info.php
   ```
2. Run it on built in php web server and open in web browser, e.g. for ubuntu:

   ```
   php -S localhost:8000 | firefox http://localhost:8000/info.php
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround script to obtain `phpinfo()` in HTML from CLI. It uses the [PHP built-in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# CONFIGURATION
server_port=8000
temp_php_file=temp-phpinfo.php
result_file=result-phpinfo.html

# EXECUTION
echo "<?php phpinfo();" > $temp_php_file
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    php -S localhost:${server_port} &
    pid=$!
else
    php -c ${1} -S localhost:${server_port} &
    pid=$!
fi
sleep 1
echo $(curl -L http://localhost:${server_port}/${temp_php_file}) > $result_file
kill $pid
rm $temp_php_file
```

Usage: `$ ./script.sh /path/to/php.ini` (path to `php.ini` is optional)

In this example, result is stored in `result-phpinfo.html`. Change the configuration as you wish.